# How to hide Sign-In dropdown in SharePoint 2013/16?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, 2016, menu-item

My objective is to hide the Sign-in dropdown. for that I have few approaches:

1. Hide using CSS
2. Hide using js
3. Using custom js method to display the username

I am looking for the first two approaches. I tried to hide it using CSS but it's not working, even though I have used js to remove it's `onclick` method which is removed, but dropdown is still coming.

Do we have any setting in `Snippet gallery` for Sign-In control to hide its menu?

[image]

Comment: entire dropdown/menu, need to show only user name.

Comment: Why I voted down: **1**. you are using id which might change environment to environment, in my case `$("#zz5_Menu_t").lenth` is returning 0. **2** you posted the answer after my final comment which is pretty straightforward. **3** whats the use of PnP SharePoint PowerShell here?

Answer (score 0):

If you go with a CSS solution, there are three things you need to do. Hide the drop down box, hide the drop down box arrow, and change the cursor to not visually indicate that it is a link.

```
/* Hide the drop down */
#welcomeMenuBox .ms-core-menu-box {
  display: none;
}

/* Hide the arrow */
#welcomeMenuBox .ms-core-menu-arrow,
#welcomeMenuBox .ms-menu-althov-active span.ms-menu-hovarw {
  display: none !important; /* !important included to override inline SharePoint style */
}

/* Alter cursor style */
#welcomeMenuBox .ms-core-menu-root {
  cursor:  default;
}
```